# Command Prompt to Enable ports in Windows Firewall

Tags: networking, powershell, cmd.exe, firewall, port

I was experimenting and was not able to find an way to enable rules/ports under Inbound Rules in Windows Firewall.

Every thing I've tried so far only shows or creates something new such as this

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="NetBIOS UDP Port 137" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=137
```

Essentially I want to enable rule for local port such as 137 UDP as opposed to do it manually in Windows Firewall -> Inbound Rules

I want to be able to do it regardless of the name of the rule and just enable based on the local port xxx.

Such as 137 UDP, 445 TCP etc

Is this even possible?

I tried also

```
netsh advfirewall firewall dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=137
```

Comment: try using the firewall `Get-*` cmdlet to get the rules that refer to that port ... and then pass the result to the matching `Set-*` cmdlet. that would let you do something like `Toggle-FireWallPort - port 137` to flip the rules for that port off/on.

Answer (score 1):

Open powershell as administrator. To create a rule for UDP port 137, type

```PS
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "NetBIOS UDP Port 137" -Direction inbound -Profile Any -Action Allow -LocalPort 137 -Protocol UDP
```

To enable the rule, type:

```PS
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "NetBIOS UDP Port 137"
```

- [New-NetFirewallRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2019-ps)
- [Enable-NetFirewallRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/enable-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2019-ps)